# Issues in rooting Galaxy Note2 GT N7100

Tags: rooting, samsung, samsung-galaxy-note-2

I tried to root my Galaxy Note 2 GT N7100 using the following link

http://galaxynote2root.com/galaxy-note-2-root/how-to-root-galaxy-note-2-on-linuxubuntu/2/

but after flashing recovery image using heimdall i am not getting the recovery interface.The heimdall flash shows successful and reboots the phone. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution if we didn't reboot to recovery after installation for the first time the custom recovery will be overwritten by the device
heimdall has a --no-reboot option. Successfully Installed CM13 in my Galaxy Note 2